# How to fasten up MATLAB function 'mscohere'

Tags: matlab

Is there any hack how to fasten up MATLAB funcion mscohere? I'm computing coherence between each 2 of 26 large vectors. Takes lots of time.

I'm using this piece of code for every pair of vectors.

```
coherenceMatrix{i,j} = mscohere(double(data.ch(indexes(i)).data),double(data.ch(indexes(j)).data),WINDOW,NOVERLAP) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a hack to improve the mscohere, but if you need multiple calls to mscohere, the parallel computing toolbox could help speed up the process.  The following code runs 2.5x faster (4.7 s vs 11.8s) when I use four workers with `parfor` vs a regular `for` loop:

```
rng default
r = randn(16384,26);
h = fir1(30,0.2,rectwin(31));
h1 = ones(1,10)/sqrt(10);
tic
cxy_outer=cell(size(r,2),1);
parfor i =1:size(r,2)
    cxy_inner=cell(size(r,2),1);
    for j= 1:size(r,2)
        if i<j
            x=filter(h1,1,r(:,i));
            y=filter(h,1,filter(h1,1,r(:,j)));
            cxy_inner{j}=mscohere(x,y,hanning(1024),512,1024);
        end
    end
    cxy_outer{i}=cxy_inner;
end
toc
```

Edit: To save the output results, `parfor` has some rules on how a variable can be sliced- hence the "cell array of cell arrays"